# heroku down migration and rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed the latest to heroku and when trying to db:migrate I got migration rolled back message. What do I need to do to migrate. I tried running heroku run rake db:migrate:up VERSION= for this particular migration and didn't help. I ran status on heroku migrations and two appear to be down. Same locally returns all up. What do I need to do to migrate?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you did not create the table "likes" before the migration file called
"AddPresenceToLikes".

You can edit this migration file and add (before the rest of the content) :

```
create_table :likes do |t|
** your table columns here **
end
```

Comment: changed migration, please see the screen. same result

Comment: thank you, it worked i just had to push the changes to heroku for them to apply